# When a checkbox becomes checked, remove class from labels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a basic form validation script, and now I'm trying to reset the errors that occur if a user doesn't fill in a required field.

For checkboxes and radio buttons, I've added the class `error` to their labels. The HTML code for this looks like this:

```
<input class="required" id="Example31" name="Example3" type="checkbox" />
<label for="Example31" class="error">Example Input 3 Option 1</label>

<input class="required" id="Example32" name="Example3" type="checkbox" />
<label for="Example32" class="error">Example Input 3 Option 2</label>

<input class="required" id="Example4" name="Example4" type="radio" />
<label for="Example4" class="error">Example Input 4</label>
```

To add the errors, I figure out if the any checkbox with the same name is checked, using this script:

```
$("input.required").each(function() {
    // check checkboxes and radio buttons
        if ($(this).is(":checkbox") || $(this).is(":radio")) {
            var inputName = $(this).attr("name");
            if (!$("input[name=" + inputName + "]").is(":checked")) {
                var inputId = $(this).attr("id");
                $("label[for=" + inputId + "]").addClass("error");
                error = true;
            };
        };
    // end checkboxes and radio buttons
});
```

How can I remove the errors without having to modify the HTML? I'm drawing a complete blank. Here's what I'm thinking:

1. Figure out the name associated with each label that has an error
2. Find the checkbox or radio button that has that ID
3. Figure out the checkbox or radio buttons name
4. Find the rest of the checkboxes or radio buttons with the same name
5. Find those inputs IDs
6. Find labels with those names
7. Clear the errors off of those labels

I'm a t loss, though. If anyone  can help, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to remove errors from all labels at once?

Comment: When do you need to remove the errors? When the `checkbox` is `unchecked`?

Comment: When it becomes checked. Sorry, went out to lunch as soon as I posted this. I'll test the code in the error below in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it myself using this:

```
$("input.required").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checkbox") || $(this).is(":radio")) {
        var inputName = $(this).attr("name");
        var labelFor = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).click(function() {
            $("input[name=" + inputName + "]").each(function() {
                var labelFor = $(this).attr("id");
                $("label[for=" + labelFor + "]").removeClass("error");
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have converted your "thinking" into code. See if this works for you...

```
// Figure out the name associated with each label that has an error
$(".error").each(function() {
    var m = $(this).attr('for');

    // Find the checkbox or radio button that has that ID
    $("input[id=" + m + "]").each(function() {

        // Figure out the checkbox or radio buttons name
        var n = $(this).attr('name');

        // Find the rest of the checkboxes or radio buttons with the same name
        $("input[name=" + n + "]").not(this).each(function() {

            // Find those inputs IDs
            i = $(this).attr('id');

            // Find labels with those names
            $("label[for=" + i + "]").each() {

                // Clear the errors off of those labels
                $(this).removeClass("error");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It gives me an error at the last `}` saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`